# AngularJs - Router - ng-View - remote web address

Tags: angularjs

**I have the following router assignment:**

```
  .when('/WebMail', { controller: HomeCtrl, templateUrl: 'http://webmail.mycompany.com' })
```

When I tried to embed that page into the ng-view from a link on the page with the ng-view, I receive the following error:

```
 Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

I imagine that is Angular saying it cannot define the remote address as a template.

**Can I not assigned a remote web page into an ng-view via the router? If so, how?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if this is a Rube Goldberg job but I solved my problem by:

Creating a dynamic iframe on a local template pointing to the remote address.

In other words:

.when('/WebMail', { controller: HomeCtrl, templateUrl: '\templates\webMail.html' })

**webMail.html:**

```
    <iframe src="{{myAngular.iFrameSrc}}"> </iframe>
```